# I have an error with my return value, it says it isn't initialized but I have it initialized in a if then statement right above it

Tags: java, methods

I have an error with my return value, it says it isn't initialized but I have it initialized in an if then statement right above it.

```
public static String leapYear(int n) {
    int j;
    int r;
    int f;
    j = n % 4;
    String check;
    if (j == 0) {
        r = n % 100;
        if (r == 0) {
            f = n % 400;
            if (f == 0) {
                check = ("The year is a leap year.");
            }
        }
    } else {
        check = ("The year is not a leap year.");
    }
    return check;
}
```

Comment: No you haven't. Not in all cases, anyway. What happens if `j == 0` but `r != 0` or `f !=0`?

Comment: I have an else statement right under it that initializes it in that case. I think?

Comment: That `else` only catches if `j != 0`, though. So if `j == 0`, that `else` is never executed.

Comment: Try to provide the default value at least to understand by complier.

Comment: I edited your question and properly indented your code. Perhaps that may help to visualize the flow through the `if` statements?

Answer (score 1):

Please try to remove the else part and put the value in the form of initalization of your `String`:

```
    public static String leapYear(int n){
    int j;
    int r;
    int f;
    j=n%4;
    String check = "The year is not a leap year.";
    if(j==0){
        r=n%100;
        if(r==0){
            f=n%400;
            if(f==0){
                check=("The year is a leap year.");
            }
        }
    }/*
    else{
        check=("The year is not a leap year.");
    }*/
    return check;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If j = 0, f != 0, the value of check will not be initialized. Similarly, if j = 0, r != 0 as well.

The pattern to follow should usually be,

```
var = "initialize default value"
if (conditions)
  set var
return;
```